# Complex Conjugate confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, convolution

[image: Image From EDx site]

---

When we take the Complex conjugate sign inside the Integral (Second Equation), we can conclude that the equation inside blue box is complex conjugate of the top equation "ONLY IF H(.) Real". well so my question is why h(.) has to be real ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because otherwise$$\overline{h(\lambda)e^{-j\omega\lambda}}=\overline{h(\lambda)}e^{-j(-\omega)\lambda}.$$Why should the RHS be equal to $\displaystyle h(\lambda)e^{-j(-\omega)\lambda}$?

Comment: only just to show that it is complex conjugate of each other